# How to troubleshoot the module nesting limit has been exceeded error in PowerShell V5?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-module

Just installed management framework 5 production preview, my profile won't load anymore with the following error

> Get-Module : Cannot load the module 'UserInfo.psm1' because the module nesting limit has been exceeded. Modules can only be nested
>   to 10 levels. Evaluate and change the order in which you are loading modules to prevent exceeding the nesting limit, and then try running your script again.

Is there a way to get more details?
I tried to trace execution with `set-psdebug -trace 2`, but I can't see the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Found it, I had same modules loaded from .psd1 `RequiredModules = @('coresmac','activedirectory')` and from the .psm1 `#requires -modules ActiveDirectory,userinfo` .

As the requires instruction appears as a comment it was quite easy to miss it ...